# Display Woocommerce sales greater than $50

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Using Woocommerce to accept donations on website. Want to display donations (orders) over $50 on the frontend.
Can't seem to filter out the orders under $50 (they still show).

```
echo '<div class="sales-admin"><b>SALES:</b><ol>';
    $orders = wc_get_orders( array(
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
            'post_status' => 'wc-completed',
            'posts_per_page'=> '5',
            'meta_query' =>
                array(
                    'key'       => 'total',
                    'value'      => '50',
                    'compare'   => '>',
                    'type' => 'numeric'
                ),
    ) );
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
     $order = new WC_Order( $order->ID );
     
     $items = $order->get_items();
     foreach( $items as $item ) {
      // $product_id = $item['product_id'];
      // if ( $post->ID == $product_id ) { echo '<li>' . $order->get_billing_first_name() . ' ' . $order->get_billing_last_name() . '</li>'; }
        echo '<li>' . $order->get_billing_first_name() . ' ' . $order->get_billing_last_name() . ': ' . $order->total . '</li>';
     }            
    } 
    echo '</ol></div>';
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks to @Thomas K I revised it so that I am passing the `total` instead of the `meta_query`.
But I still cannot filter out orders below $50. I think it is because the total is a string.
When I change my args to

```
$orders = wc_get_orders( array(
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
            'post_status' => 'wc-completed',
            'posts_per_page'=> '5',
            'total' => '50.00',
               
    ) );
```

then I do get all orders at exactly $50.
So I tried

```
$orders = wc_get_orders( array(
            'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
            'post_status' => 'wc-completed',
            'posts_per_page'=> '5',
            'total' =>
                array(
                    'value'      => '50',
                    'compare'   => '>=',
                    'type' => 'numeric'
                ),
    ) );
```

It doesn't work. I still get all results including less than $50.

Answer (score 1):

When filtering on the order you should use the `_order_total` meta key, `total` key doesn't exists

Went looking into a database, found an order for the type `shop_order`, used that `postID` to check the `post_meta` and found the key `order_total`

**UPDATE**

On my local machine it worked with `_order_total`. you should also be able to just pass the `total` field on instead of a meta query.

```
$args = array(
    'total' => '>=' . ( 50)
);
$orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
```

see more on `wc_get_orders` https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query

Comment: This did not work for me but is giving me a better understanding. I did a var dump and found the `order_total` under `internal_meta_keys`. But the `order_total` is blank. when I go up to the top of the dump I do see a `total` key with a value. How do I query for that?
I tried: 
```'total' => array(
     'value' => 50,
     'compare' => '>=',
),```
but didn't work.

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your help @Thomas K. I'm getting closer but still not working. 
I think it is a problem because the total is a string.  When I type `'total'  => '>=' .  ( 50)` nothing happens. I tried using `'total' => 50` and nothing happens but when I type `'total' => '50.00'` I do get all the results that are exactly $50. So I tried `'total' => array(      'value' => 50, 'compare' => '>=', 'type' => 'numeric', )` but that still does not work.